# Update hash maps collection values based on another hash maps collection

Tags: csv, clojure, hashmap, updates

I have the following hash maps collection:

```
(def master-data [
    {:code "1234" :name "Jhon"}
    {:code "5678" :name "Brown"}
    {:code "9999" :name "Steven"}
])
```

and I have data in csv file with this information:

```
old_code,new_code,old_name,new_name
1234,2222,Jhon,Travolta
4321,3456,Steven,Cody
```

how can i change the values of inside master-data  to the new data provide by the csv file?

the rules are:

1. if `code` inside `master-data` found in `old_code` column in csv file then change `code` value using `new_code` value from csv file.
2. if `name` inside `master-data` found in `old_name` column in csv file then change `name` value using `new_name` value from csv file.

Comment: Which Clojure CSV library are you using?

Comment: @jmargolisvt: i am using data.csv-0.1.2

Comment: can you post the code you have tried?

Comment: @leonardoborges good progress so far, now i can transform `code` and `name` based on `old_code/new_code` and `old_name/new_name` references, by hardcoding them into vectors. My problem now is how to extract the csv source file into 4 vectors : old_code,new_code,old_name,new_name so it can easily to update the references

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to map your master data, checking every item from csv and updating master data entry if needed.

```
(defn update-if [item key check new-val]
  "utility function. updates a value for a key, setting it to new-val if it equals check"
  (if (= (item key) check)
    (assoc item key new-val)
    item))

(defn update-data [data mappings]
  (map (fn [item]
         (reduce (fn [item [old-code new-code old-name new-name]]
                   (-> item
                       (update-if :code old-code new-code)
                       (update-if :name old-name new-name)))
                 item
                 mappings))
       data))
```

in repl:

```
ttask.core> (def master-data [{:code "1234" :name "Jhon"}
                              {:code "5678" :name "Brown"}
                              {:code "9999" :name "Steven"}])
#'ttask.core/master-data

ttask.core> (def input "old_code,new_code,old_name,new_name
1234,2222,Jhon,Travolta
4321,3456,Steven,Cody")
#'ttask.core/input

ttask.core> (update-data master-data (rest (csv/read-csv input)))
({:code "2222", :name "Travolta"} {:code "5678", :name "Brown"} {:code "9999", :name "Cody"})
```

Comment: great answer!! thanks @leetwinski. now i don't have to hardcoding the references mapping into my existings codes